# How to implement insert vector c++?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, insert

I have to implement a vector class with `operator[]`, rule of 5, `push_back`, and `insert`.

```cpp
template<class T>
class MyVector
{
private:
    int size_;
    int capacity_;
    T* data;
public:
    typedef T* it;

    it begin();
    it end();
    void push_back(const T& value);
```

I started to create constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, move assignment operator.

I implemented the `begin()` and `end()` like this:

```cpp
template<class T>
typename MyVector<T>::it MyVector<T>::begin()
{
    return data;
}

template<class T>
typename MyVector<T>::it MyVector<T>::end()
{
    return data + size();
}
```

I don't know how to implement `push_back()` and `insert()`.

For `push_back()`, I thought about something like this:

```cpp
void push_back(const T & v)
{
    if (size_ < capacity_)
        data [size_++] = v;
}
```

But for `insert()`, I have no idea.

Could you help me please to implement `insert()`?

Comment: Please post real code / a [mcve]. What are all those `...` ?

Comment: i couldn't because it is to large

Comment: Then that is not a minimal example. The problem here is that you are asking how to do this without having tried it. Give us what you thought would work and it is easier to help. No one is going to write the code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `push_back()` is not implemented correctly.  It needs to grow the array when the `size_` is equal to the `capacity_`, to make room for the new value being pushed.

Likewise, your `insert()` also needs to grow the array, if needed.  It can then figure out the index where the new value should go, shift all of the elements *after* that index up one slot in the array, and then assign the new value to the element at that index.

Try something like this:

```cpp
template<class T>
void MyVector<T>::grow()
{
    static const int delta = ...; // <-- use whatever value makes sense for your use case...
    int new_cap = capacity_ + delta;
    T* new_data = new T[new_cap];
    for(int i = 0; i < size_; ++i) {
        new_data[i] = std::move(data[i]);
    }
    delete[] data;
    data = new_data;
    capacity_ = new_cap;
}

template<class T>
void MyVector<T>::push_back(const T & v)
{
    if (size_ == capacity_)
        grow();

    data[size_] = v;
    ++size_;
}

template<class T>
void MyVector<T>::insert(typename MyVector<T>::it pos, const T & v)
{
    int index = pos - data;
    if (index < 0 || index > size_)
        return; // or throw...

    if (size_ == capacity_)
        grow();

    for(int i = size_ - 1; i >= index; --i)
        data[i+1] = data[i];

    data[index] = v;
    ++size_;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/GhO5M6)

Answer (score 0):

For insert you must.

- make room for the extra data. (as you also need to do in push_back/emplace_back).
- move the current data from the insertion point to the new offset.
- copy the inserted data in.

Comment: so my push back is not ok ?

Comment: @loveProgram you need to add code to make room, if capacity is not large enough.

Comment: and do you have any ideea how to print the vector, to see if it's working ?

Comment: If your begin() & end() works then you can print it like you do std::vector, else you could use operator[] which you should also implement.

Comment: and how i am suppose to print if i implemented [] ?

Comment: for (auto i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) std::cout << vec[i];

Comment: @loveProgram Use a for loop, just like you would with a regular array or vector. You're trying to write something that emulates arrays and vectors, so similar code should work with both.

Comment: @loveProgram Or, since you are clearly using C++11 or later, you can use a range-for loop instead, as you have iterators implemented: `for(auto &value : vec) { std::cout << value; }` No `operator[]` needed for that.